# How to identify the source of a recursive edit?

Tags: recursive-edit

Every once in a while I notice that the mode name on the mode-line
says `[Emacs-Lisp]` instead of just `Emacs-Lisp`. I realise that this
indicates a recursive edit, and I can get rid of it with `C-M-c`, but
I never know what triggered it.

**Is there a way to find out the cause of a current recursive-edit?**

Comment: Oh, is that what it is? I always wondered why those square brackets appeared. At times I have also seen the major mode name double or triple square bracketed: `[[Emacs-Lisp]]`

Comment: I can think of unclean exit from edebug. Will try that out next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a "clean command" that will tell you that directly.  But `M-x debug RET` will give you the current backtrace, where you should be able to find both `recursive-edit` and its predecessor (i.e. caller).